# Excluding duplicates from a foreach loop in a WP_Query for WooCommerce products

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, foreach, woocommerce

I have a WP Query to list matching products, like this:

```
function sku_ean_sizes () {
global $product;

$current_stijlcode = $product->get_attribute( 'pa_stijlcode' );
$current_ean = $product->get_attribute( 'pa_ean' );

$postid = get_the_ID();

    $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'product',
      'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'meta_key' => '_price',
        'order' => 'asc',
      'posts_per_page' => 100,
      'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'pa_stijlcode',
      'field'    => 'slug',
      'terms'    => $current_stijlcode,
    ),
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'pa_ean',
      'field'    => 'slug',
      'terms'    => $current_ean,
    )
  )
      );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
      while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();



global $product;

foreach( wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, 'pa_maat' ) as $attribute_value ){
  echo '<span>' . $attribute_value . '</span>';
}

      endwhile;
    } else {
      // no sku matches found
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

I would like to use the foreach loop to list the found product attributes attached to the products found with the WP Query:

```
global $product;

    foreach( wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, 'pa_maat' ) as $attribute_value ){
      echo '<span>' . $attribute_value . '</span>';
    }
```

This code works. However, the `$attribute_value` variable outputs duplicate records. This makes sense, as multiple products could have the same output.

What adjustment can i make so it excludes duplicate values?

In context; This is to display **all** available sizes for a specific product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

You should use a foreach loop to set all the values in an array avoiding duplicates

Then, using `implode()` PHP function, you will display all attributes term names without duplicates.

This partial code to replace yours, will display the non duplicated attribute term names for all products at once:

```
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $loop->have_posts() ):
    $maat_term_names = array();
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ): 
        $loop->the_post();

        // Set the attribute term names in an array avoiding duplicates
        foreach( wc_get_product_terms( $loop->post->ID, 'pa_maat' ) as $attribute_value ):
            $maat_term_names[$attribute_value] = $attribute_value;
        endforeach;
    endwhile;

    // Sorting (ordering)
    sort($maat_term_names);

    // Here you display attribute term names without duplicates (coma separated)
    echo '<span>' . implode( '</span>, <span>', $maat_term_names ) . '</span> ';

else:
   echo '<span>No SKUs matches found</span>';
endif;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: This code works! Thank you so much. Is there a way to let the output, order by number? Right now, the output could be this:

40 , 41 , 42 , 39.5 , 44

Comment: EDIT: Whereas it should be: 39.5 , 40 , 41 , 42 , 44

Comment: @Matthias Updated my code adding this line: `sort($maat_term_names);`

Comment: You are a live-saver. Thank you so much.